# File does not exist when searching custom partial view paths

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8

I'm getting a strange issue on our MVC app.  We are inheriting the RazorViewEngine to create a custom view engine, to facilitate custom logic in the arrangement of views.

We have a list of potential view paths:

```
            PartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
        {
            "~/Views/Partial/Shared/Base/$thing/{0}.$otherthing.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Partial/Shared/Base/$thing/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Partial/Shared/Base/{0}.$otherthing.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Partial/Shared/Base/{0}.cshtml"
        };
```

Then we override the FileExists method, like:

```
        protected override bool FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, string virtualPath)
    {
        return base.FileExists(controllerContext, this.ParsePath(controllerContext, virtualPath));
    }
```

ParsePath method looks like:

```
        private string ParsePath(ControllerContext controllerContext, string virtualPath)
    {
        string newPath = virtualPath;
        BaseController controller = controllerContext.Controller as BaseController;
        if (controller != null)
        {
            if (controller.Model != null)
            {

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(controller.Model.Thing))
                {
                    newPath = newPath.Replace("$thing", controller.Model.Thing);
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(controller.Model.OtherThing))
                {
                    newPath = newPath.Replace("$otherthing", controller.Model.OtherThing);
                }
            }
        }

        return newPath;
    }
```

This works fine locally, but after publishing to a Win 2012, IIS8 box, I'm seeing the following error:

The file '/Views/Partial/Shared/Base/Footer.blar.cshtml' does not exist.

```
TargetSite: System.Web.Compilation.BuildResult GetVPathBuildResultInternal(System.Web.VirtualPath, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)

StackTrace: at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) yadda yadda yadda
```

'/Views/Partial/Shared/Base/Footer.cshtml' does exist, why does it throw the exception?

My hunch is the code is fine and its a issue with IIS - I've checked that the sites are running integrated mode etc...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of an optimization MVC has when you have the application set to debug="false".  Once I set debug="true", This error went away for me.